# Custom operator to suppress sink context

Tags: raku

```
multi sub infix:<*>( Numeric $i, Block $b ) { &$b($_) for ^($i.Int); }
3 * { .say };
```

Yields

```
Useless use of "*" in expression "3 * { .say }" in sink context
```

How do I get rid of that and make my operator work? I know I could assign it to `$` or something else, but I don't want that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this line to the start of your code:

```
proto sub infix:<*> ( | --> Nil ) {*}
```

See [my answer to **Impossible to put a map in sink context**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60198442/1077672) for a little on the `--> Nil` part of this (along with a boatload of irrelevant stuff too) including Larry's 2012 comment:

> `--> Nil` seems like pretty good documentation of a procedure done only for its side-effects

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that by declaring a new `proto`, all existing `infix:<*>` candidates get hidden.